# hover on task subject in Report

Tags: reporting, tasks

I have an "open tasks" report and I would like to see the task details when I hover over the task subject in the report.
Can this be done somehow?

Comment: can you be little specific with screen shots ?

Comment: @Mohith - the same popup with task details when you hover over the task in the home tab task list